# How to play a song from a random time in javascript ? (Ex:from the 5th second)

Tags: javascript, audio, random, time, playback

I'm trying to play a song from a specific time code. This,
document.getElementById('rock').play(); 
play the song from the beginning. Is there a way to choose the beginnning time?
Thank you.

document.getElementById('rock').play();

Comment: Why don’t you google that question? MDN has great documentation on how play() works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTMLMediaElement.currentTime property gives the current playback time in seconds. Setting this value seeks the media to the new time.

[HTMLMediaElement.currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime#Value)

```
let song = document.getElementById('rock');
song.currentTime = 35;
```